# projection formula for generalized multiplicative cohomology theory

Tags: reference-request, at.algebraic-topology, cohomology

Let $E^{\bullet}$ be a multiplicative generalized cohomology theory and $\cup$ be the induced cup product. It is known that we can define a Gysin map $\iota_*:E^{\bullet}(Z)\rightarrow E^{\bullet}(X)$ for any $E^{\bullet}$-oriented closed smooth embedding $\iota:Z\hookrightarrow X$ between smooth manifolds via the Thom isomorphism.

> Do we expect a projection formula $\iota_*(\iota^*\alpha\cup\beta)=\alpha\cup\iota_*\beta$ ?

If not, do we have a counterexample? If yes, do we have a reference?

Answer (score 2):

This is in the book

*Dyer, Eldon*, Cohomology theories, Mathematics Lecture Note Series. New York-Amsterdam: W. A. Benjamin, Inc. xiii, 183 p. (1969). [ZBL0182.57002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0182.57002).

See Theorem 7 on page 54. It's true more generally for $E^\bullet$-oriented continuous maps.